# No aparece el icono de mi app en React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

He generado mi apk tal cual como lo dice la documentacion de react-native y no me da problemas en ningun momento, ejecuto el comando `react-native run-android --variant=release` y funciona perfectamente en el emulador, pero cuando instalo el apk en el emulador o en mi telefono no me aparece el icono por ningun lado y no puedo ejectuarla.

Si me meto en la configuracion para desinstalar la app que acabo de instalar si aparece pero por ningun otro lado puedo verla para poder ejecutarla

Cualquier ayuda o idea es agradecida.

Comment: Debes revisar [ask], es indispensable para obtener la ayuda necesaria, aporta datos y se especifico,  ¿esto es para iOS y Android? mencionas que no se muestran los iconos, pero ¿has agregado iconos o que has realizado para que aparezca?

Comment: por ahora solo lo utilizo en android, la app tiene un icono pero el problema no es que el icono no aparezca o este dañado, la cosa es que no aparece la app por ningun lado es como si no estuviera instalada, pero si me meto en las opciones de las app como si fuera a desinstar una, alli si me aparece, incluso cuando la instalo por primera vez me muestra el boton de listo y el boton de abrir pero este ultimo me aparece desabilitado

Answer (score 1):

Algo tarde pero espero que a alguien le funcione de ser necesario.

Tenía el mismo problema, y este era causado porque en el `<intent-filter>` de mi AndroidManifiest no tenía declarado un category que hiciera referencia al *LAUNCHER*

```
    <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <data android:scheme="com.myapp" />
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

para solucionarlo lo separé en dos bloques `<intent-filter>`, añadí la referencia a *LAUNCHER* y quedó solucionado:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="com.myapp" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>
```